# wordpress - other posts of the same category on post page

Tags: php, wordpress

i need to link the lasts 5 posts of the same category after the post content in wordpress. Anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the loop declare some var that will hold post category. Than query posts with that cat.

Here is example:

```
<?php
$cat_id = 0; // declare var
if(have_posts()):
  while(have_posts()):
    // do what you usually do
    $cat_id = $post->post_category;
  endwhile;
endif;

// here you will get posts and make html output
$last_in_cat = get_posts('posts_per_page=5&cat='.$cat_id);
foreach($last_in_cat as $cat_post):
?>
<a href="<?php $cat_post->guid ?>"><?php $cat_post->post_title ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain anithing you want using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). It is very flexible and you should definitely start using it.
It is just like the SQL queryes.